# How convert 1/2 to binary?

Tags: binary

How convert 1/2 to binary?
isn't it 0.1111
$1/2$ result $0$  $(1/2)*2=1$ result $0.1$    $2*2>1$ result $0.11 $ etc.

Comment: How do you convert $1/10$ to decimal?

Comment: $0.1_2=0\cdot 2^0+1\cdot 2^{-1}=\frac 1 2$. $0.\bar 1_2$ would be $=1$, much like $0.\bar 9_{10}=1$.

Comment: if i didn't want to go through decimal?

Comment: as Gerry suggested: $1/2=2^{-1}\dots$

Answer (score 6):

To expand upon [Gerry Myerson's excellent comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/676264/how-convert-1-2-to-binary#comment1420390_676264),

If you're working in base 10, and want to get 1/10, you do two steps, as shown in the diagram below

- Write the numerator, 1, as `01.` (add in the decimal point and a leading zero)
- Move the decimal point one space to the left, to get `0.1`

[image]

So if you're working in base 2, and want to get 1/2, you need to do similar: write 1 in base 2, add the binary point and leading zero, and then move the binary point.

---

Each digit to the right of the binary point is some negative power of 2. So

$$ \text{binary }  0.1111 = 0\times2^0 + 1\times2^{-1}  + 1\times2^{-2}  + 1\times2^{-3} + 1\times2^{-4}$$

In decimal this is 0.9375. The more 1s you add after the binary point the closer you get to 1.

---

In case you're wondering how 1/2 is stored in a computer it is held in "scientific notation" style:

$$ 1/2 = 1 \times 2^{-1}$$

The computer stores the mantissa (1) and the exponent($-1$). (In the case of signed numbers things are a little more complicated. Easy to find info on the internet, e.g. [here](http://kipirvine.com/asm/workbook/floating_tut.htm).)